# Why ParallelFlux doesnt have collectList() similar to Flux?

Tags: project-reactor

The Flux has collectList() which is very convenient to use however there is no collectList() in ParallelFlux,I am trying to understand the reason behind to omit collectList() in ParallelFlux.

Answer (score 4):

As ParallelFlux is created to run streams in parallel in different threads, the order of execution is not the same as the order of first stream so flux does not know the right order in which to collect the stream.

- It offers you `collect()` to collect it by your rule
- It offers you `collectSortedList()` to collect in a sorted way you choose
- If you just want to collect it as a `List` and the order doesn't meter you can do it like this

  ```
  Integer integer[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15};
    ParallelFlux.from(Flux.fromArray(integer), 4)
            .runOn(Schedulers.parallel())
            .sequential()
            .collectList()
            .subscribe(integer1 -> System.out.println(integer1));
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the workaround to get unordered list from Flux.I want to know why Integer integer[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15};
    ParallelFlux.from(Flux.fromArray(integer), 4)
            .runOn(Schedulers.parallel()).collectList() Api is not offered to get unordered list

Comment: If you put the .sequencial(), will you still have the benefit of doing the processing in parallel ? because otherwise, it wouldn't make sense to use ParallelFlux, right ?

Comment: Does anyone have any conclusion about what @Jonathan said? I have the same doubt

Comment: yes it will benefit from parallel just the order will be saved

Answer (score 0):

Concatenating a list is an operation that requires a shared access to the resulting list. If you don't lock the list and you append to it from the different threads it can produce different version of the same list with missing elements. Because if two threads try to change the same element at once only one of them can persist the data back to the memory.

I.e., you need a *lock* when you append, and that's not what Reactor wants to do.

You can implement your own *collector* with locks. But that makes this function as single threaded anyway because only one of the thread may have access to the list at a time.

So if you want to append to the list it's better to do it after `sequential()`. In this case, do all the parallel work in one step using multiple threads, and then with `sequential()` dispatch the results into a single thread that merges everything into one list. In general, it cannot be faster if you try to merge from different threads, unless you have a special lock-free data structure optimized for your particular situation.